# How can i create a unique constraint for a list property on Entity Framework via Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, unique-constraint

I need to create a unique constraint for a list property on my entity object. 
How can i create one and many unique constraint?

```
public class ConstraintException
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UNQ_PMR", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UNQ_PMR", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public virtual ICollection<ConstraintExceptionCoverage> Coverages { get; set; }

}

public class ConstraintExceptionCoverage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CoverageId { get; set; }

    public int ConstraintExceptionId { get; set; }
}
```

### Example

> **ProductId**=44 and **Coverage Ids**={1,2,3} records exist on database. If i try to add new record ProductId=44 and Coverage Ids={1,2,3}, database warn me with unique constraint.

Comment: In the `ConstraintExceptionCoverage` table, you need to add a Unique Constraint for `CoverageId, ProductId`

Comment: But, product id does not exist in ConstraintExceptionCoverage table. Is it possible without product id? @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: Sorry, your classes just don't make sense to me. `ConstraintException` should have a `ConstraintExceptionId` and `ConstraintExceptionCoverage` should have a `ConstraintExceptionCoverageId`. I cannot tell you which should be the actual properties with what you have posted

Comment: Yes, you're right. Id columns stay on base class which name "Entity", but i'll edit the question text.

Comment: Well, the only way to add a constraint at the database level is by doing so in the ConstraintExceptionCoverage table. You would need to replicate the ProductId field if you want this checked by the database.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much @CamiloTerevinto